# ElasticSearch Relationships

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi Friends Please Help Me ...

I Have some doubt regarding the relationships in elastic search.

I will explain my doubt with the following example

**Step 1:
I have created an index named "books" in elastic search**

example.com:9200/books/

**Step 2:
Then i created a type named 'author' and data inserted to it**

POST example.com:9200/books/author/1
{
"fname" : "David","lname":"Thomas"
}

POST example.com:9200/books/author/2
{
"fname" : "Hamton","lname":"Vergo"
}

**Step 3: 
Then Created a mapping for another type 'authorbook' which is child of 'author'**

POST example.com:9200/books/authorbook/_mapping

{"authorbook":{"_parent":{"type":"author"}}}

**Step 4 : 
Then i inserted data for authorbook**

POST example.com:9200/books/authorbook/100?parent=1
{
"bookname" : "Bookname1"
}

POST example.com:9200/books/authorbook/200?parent=1
{
"bookname" : "Bookname2"
}

POST example.com:9200/books/authorbook/300?parent=2
{
"bookname" : "Bookname3"
}

**step :5
Then i created a mapping for another type named 'publisher' , a child of authorbook**

POST example.com:9200/books/publisher/_mapping

{"publisher":{"_parent":{"type":"authorbook"}}}

**Step 6:
Then i inserted data for publisher

POST example.com:9200/books/publisher/50?parent=200
{
"publname" : "publisher1"
}

POST example.com:9200/books/publisher/51?parent=200
{
"publname" : "publisher2"
}

POST example.com:9200/books/publisher/52?parent=100
{
"publname" : "publisher3"
}

**Step 7
Now i have achieved in getting the 'authorbook' details by using a post request with following body**

```
{
"query": {
    "has_parent": {
        "type": "author",
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": {
                    "or": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "fname": "Hamton"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "fname": "David"     
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

My requirement is to get the publisher details also..how can achieve that? pls help..

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to do recursive request on ES. You should probably do this first request and use the answer returned as an input of a seconde request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
             "or": [
                  {
                      "has_parent": {
                          "type": "author",
                           "query": <your query above>
                  },
                  {
                      "has_parent": {
                          "type": "author"
                          "query": {
                              "constant_score": {
                                   "filter": {
                                       "has_parent": {
                                           "type": "authorbook",
                                           "query": <some query you need for the publishers>
                                       }
                                   }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
     }
}
```

This should return you authorbooks and publishers in the same query.

**First tip**: if you use `"query": {"match_all": {}}` in a `filtered` query you can also just use a `constant_score` query instead. Then you just have to provide the filter.

**Second tip**: When indexing a grandchild like `publisher` you better provide the `routing` query parameter as well (which should point to the id of the `author`). This makes sure children and grandchildren are stored in the same shard which makes lookup faster.

In general I would advice against a complicated relationship like this though. You can see that the query is hard to read and most likely hard to debug later on. Maybe keeping it simple could be better solution. Another idea is to have `authorbook` (or just `book` as a parent and `publisher` and `author` as normal (first level) children of the `book`. Reason is that `author` and `publisher` are not related, so you actually don't need this deep nesting.